Why do nutrition facts label differ for canned Garbanzo Beans (Chickpeas)?
Looking at canned Chickpeas Garbanzo Beans from several vendors, it seems some vendors use "prepared Garbanzo Beans" while others just used "Garbanzo Beans". Some also have noticeable calorie and protein differences.
In the ingredients list, what is the difference between "prepared garbazno beans" and regular "garbanzo beans". What would account for the caloric and other nutritional differences between vendors with seemingly identical ingredient lists?

Target - Organic Low Sodium Chickpeas Garbanzo Beans - 15oz - Good & Gather
Walmart - Great Value Organic Chick Pea Garbanzo Beans, 15 oz Can
Goya - Organic Chick Peas
Whole Foods Market - 365 by Whole Foods Market, Organic Unsalted Garbanzo Beans, 13.4 Ounce 


I’m closing this question because the question lacks a good argument for posting it on the chemistry site.

Different ingredients and their ratio with different procedures lead to different results. If you want details, you need to ask producers.
